# Who can it be…?

Tags: word, visual, rebus

Who can it be…? Can you solve the rebuses?

[image]

Answer the following three questions:

1. Where does he/she live?
2. What is his/her name?
3. What is his/her job?

---

**Hint 1:**

> The mirror inverts the dots of the Braille code.

**Hint 2:**

> [image] is ____ the [image], so [image] + ____ + [image] = ?

**Hint 3:**

> Phanerozoic, Proterozoic, Archean and Hadean are ____.

**Hint 4:**

> The second image in *3)* represents the capital city.

Comment: Based on 3), the current rot13(CERZVRE BS ABEGUJRFG GREEVGBEVRF) is rot13(OBO ZPYRBQ) who lives in rot13(LRYYBJXAVSR), but that doesn't fit 1) and 2).

Comment: @shoover I added another hint.

Comment: @Lypyrhythm, do the numbers in the rebus portion correspond with the numbers in the "answer these three questions" section?

Comment: @zeethreepio No, they don’t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Partial answer*

### Hint 1

> inverting the braille code *not really like a mirror* (dots will be blanks, blanks will be dots) gives us   **d e s**   (thx to M Oehm)

### Hint 2

> **PA** (Abbreviation of Pennsylvania) is **in** the **tea**

### Hint 3

> Phanerozoic, Proterozoic, Archean and Hadean are [*eon*s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geological_history_of_Earth).

### Hint 4

> Canadian Maple Leaf -> Canada
>  Capitol City -> Ottawa, no, wait!

## Answers:

1. Where does he/she live?

   > *Rebus 3:*
   >  Pic 1: Maple leaf of Canada => Canada
   >
   >  Pic 2: Hint 4 gives "Capitol City of Canada"
   >
   >  Pic 3: Isaac Newton -> Newton
   >
   >  Pic 4: Eons => Newton - eon = NWT (North-West-Territories)
   >
   >  And the capitol city of the North-West-Territories of Canada is **yellowknife**
2. What is his/her name?

   > *Rebus 1:*
   >  Pic 1: maybe a "wheel hub" or "hub" or "nave", first thought was "mount" but as this is now the name...
   >
   >  Pic 2: desert
   >
   >  Pic 3: **d e s** (Hint 1)
   >
   >  Pic 4: "wood" or "logs" or "pile"
   >
   >  gives ... Ill Pick **Hub + Desert - des + Wood = Hubert Wood**
3. What is his/her job?

   > *Rebus 2:*
   >  PA in Tea => **Paintee**, a female painter

Comment: Note how the first hint specifically says that the mirror "inverts" (not reflects) the code. Not that I know how a mirror could do that, but the set of letters you get will be useful for making a sensible name.

Comment: Do the numbers in the rebus correspond with the numbers of "Answer the following three questions"? If so, you're answers make sense but they're applied to the wrong questions. I asked OP above ^

Comment: Good job, I accepted your answer. Also, the solution to rebus *2)* is supposed to be “painte**r**“, not “paintee.”

Comment: Where do you get the -er from, @Lypyrhythm? I can see the PA in TEA but not in TER....

Comment: Um, okay, so it's not a real person?

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer:

> 1) bearing/wheel hub (Bering ?) + desert - braille? (meaningless) + firewood
>
> **2) Patty (Patricia, possibly Patrick) : PA (Abbr. of Pennsylvania) + tea**
>
> 3) Canadian maple leaf
>     -> government?
>     -> Isaac Newton - Cambrian? (Newton taught at Cambridge?)